# Disable query strings in access log

Tags: apache, logging

Long story short, user passwords are being passed plain text via url (horrible, yes, but not my idea), and this query string is being stored in the access log, which we clearly don't want so obvious.

Is there a way to prevent query strings from being stored in the access log without disabling CustomLog?

Comment: What's your current [CustomLog format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) set to?

Comment: `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog "logs/access.log" common`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `common` log format includes the query string in `%r` (first line of request)

What you can do is to add a new log format (keep the old one for reference, no need to remove it)

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%m %U %H\" %>s %b" common_no_querystring
```

where `%m` is the method (GET/POST), `%U` is the URL requested without querystring and `%H` is the HTTP version for the request. This will output the same line as `%r`, except the query string.

Then all you need to do is change the customlog line to;

```
CustomLog "logs/access.log" common_no_querystring
```

and you'll no longer get query strings in the log.

Comment: Damn, now that's a thorough answer!

Comment: I have also come across to similar situation, and getting below error :

ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout("%h %l %u %t \"%m %U %H\" %>s %b %n") - Failed to parse pattern "%h %l %u %t \"%m %U %H\" %>s %b %n". ch.qos.logback.core.spi.ScanException: Failed to initialize Parser

Comment: But that will also not show other request parameters. How can we mask a specific request param without anonymizing the others?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Custom Log Formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats), specifically

```
%U  The URL path requested, not including any query string.
```

Comment: Thanks, as this is the essential info I needed.